# possible to discover ENI Ip address via EC2 instance meta-data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

Im using ECS to create a service that uses the awsvpc network type - thus creating ENIs on my host instances giving my ec2 instances two internal network configs and two internal Ips.

I cant seem to be able to pull out any ENI information out of the instance metadata http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ - only the original internal Ip.

Is there any way i can discover the ENI ip via querying the instance metadata or other method from within the docker container without resorting to aws-cli ?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to get the ip address of the ENI adapter with the instance meta-data:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/`

then sub in the macs to get both private ips:

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/<mac address>/local-ipv4s`